# multiple key & CSR for different CN and same attributes

Tags: linux, unix, openssl, ssl-certificate

I need to generate new keys &CSR for 17 different CN: i.e. `server1.com, server2.com ... server17.com` but they all have the same attributes:

i.e.    `C=US, ST=State, L=Town, O=Online Coputers, OU=Support Operations, CN=server1.com/emailAddress=certificates@support.com`

I generated CSR and key for CN server1.com using:

```
openssl req -out server1.com.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server1.com.key
```

and it works fine.

Is it possible to feed the attributes as constants to openssl and just change CN, would openssl support this ? in this way the command will generate keys and CSRs with same attributes but different CNs.

Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 1):

for example, you have a list file with different CN (CN.txt)

```
server1.com
server2.com
serverx.com
servery.com
```

Then you can run below command to generate keys:

```
while read line
do
  openssl req -out ${line}.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout ${line}.key
done < CN.list
```